# User profile page complaints

Tags: discussion, user-interface, profile-page

It's been a month since the new user profile. It's been long enough to try and work with it, and long enough to develop some pet peeves about it.

In particular the fact that I can no longer directly know how many answers are given to a question by the user. *I have to click another link*. I don't like that.

I'm guessing that other people might have other pet peeves, feel free to write them in the comments.

Comment: Wait, there's a link that lets you easily see how many answers a user has given to a question?  Where?  Or did I misread you somehow?

Comment: @Ilmari, I understood Asaf's statement to refer to how many answers (by anyone) have been given to a question that the user has asked.

Comment: @Ilmari: Rahul got it right.